# How to know Client abort Http Request in Nodejs (Nestjs)

Tags: node.js, fetch, nestjs, server-sent-events, abortcontroller

So I use Nestjs with Observable to serve SSE.
Client will call SSE API and wait for Server to send data.
But Client also can cancel it. The problem is I don't know how I can know when Client abort the request so I can stop querying data in Server.

Anyone knows.Thanks in advance